# Truly mocking providers

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

So basically there's no information on how to omit config/run/provider blocks on modules without doing some file load ordering hack for unit-tests. Assume the following:

```
// dependency chain for providers:
// aaa <- bbb <- ccc


angular.module('module0').provider('bbb', [
  'aaaProvider', 
  function (aaaProvider) {
    // aaaProvider definition
    ...
  });

angular.module('module1').provider('ccc', [
  'bbbProvider',
  function (bbbProvider) {
    // bbbProvider definition
    ...
  });

angular.module('module1').controller('controller', [
  function () {
    // controller definition
  }]);
```

Now assume that we are writing a unit test for `controller`. How would we do that?

```
module('module1');
inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  ...
});
```

Oops, we have a problem. `module('module1')` will trigger provider definition for `ccc`, that has dependency on `bbb`, that has dependency on `aaa`. So unless we prevent provider definition for `ccc` being triggered on `module1`, we will running code that has nothing to do with the `controller` we are unit testing.

We can mock `bbb` by using `module(function ($provide) { ... });` notation and that way we won't need to load `module0` at all.

But that doesn't solve it for `ccc`. There's no way for me to stop it from running.

**Question:** Is there a way to stop `module1` from running the definition of `ccc` provider, which has nothing to do with `controller` we are unit testing?

Things I've tried so far:

- Override definition in unit test:

  `angular.module('module1').provider('ccc', [function () {}]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create in your app.js two modules

module1internal - this module will not have dependencies and will be used for all 
your application providers

```
angular.module('module1internal', []);
```

module1 - this module depends on the module1internal and will include all other dependencies, config and run block

```
angular.module('module1', ['module1internal','bbbProvider']);
```

in your app you should use only the internal module for example instead of

```
angular.module('module1').controller('controller', [
  function () {
    // controller definition
  }]);
```

you should use

```
angular.module('module1internal').controller('controller', [
      function () {
        // controller definition
      }]);
```

The tests will look like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: TheController', function () {

  // mock second level dependencies
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('module1internal');
    module({
      bbb: {}
    });
  });

  var TheController, scope,
    cccMock;

  // mock injected providers
  beforeEach(inject(function (_ccc_) {
    cccMock = mock(_ccc_);
  }));


  // Initialise the controller and mock scope 
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    TheController = $controller('TheController', {
      $scope: scope
    });

  }));

  it(' should call ccc functionA on functionThatUsesFunctionA call', function () {
    TheController.functionThatUsesFunctionA("someValue");
    expect(cccMock.functionA).toHaveBeenCalledWith("someValue");
  });



  //create spy on all provider's methods(mock it)
  function mock(angularServiceToMock) {

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(angularServiceToMock).length; i++) {
      spyOn(angularServiceToMock, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(angularServiceToMock)[i]);
    }
    return angularServiceToMock;
  }

});
```

Comment: That's a viable solution, although it means a lot of refactoring for me (it's a huge app with hundreds of controllers, directives, providers run blocks etc.)

Comment: This is a best practice advise for new projcts.

Comment: Hmm, so some time has passed since this question had been answered. With this approach, how do you unit test individual providers inside `module1internal` without running other providers in the module?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question,in this approach there are two ways to prevent a provider from running in the test. 1) disable all public methods by converting them into spy objects (the function mock() in the example) 2) overriding the provider by adding it to the module (bbb{} in the example), the second is useful when you have  init onload that you want to prevent from running.

Comment: My question is, if we put thousand providers into a module and if we want to test only 1, how do we do it without explicitly disabling 999 other providers?

Comment: You will not be able to disable them all, but you don't have to, you need to disable only those that are injected into your tested provider, and those that cause you troubles due to external dependencies. True this requires that your application will not be a monolith with thousands of individual dependencies.