# How to work with third-party libraries when doing unit-testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm a newbie when it comes to unit-testing, I've tried to do a unit-test with Karma and Jasmine from an app that already existed.

Basically the app has a lot of dependencies from different third-party libraries being used. So when I tried to create a unit-test a stumbled upon a lot of errors from Karma/Jasmine. One of them is the screenshot below:

[image: unit-test-error]

From the screenshot, I'm getting an **unknown provider: socketFactoryProvider**, which I've traced down and found out that it belongs to the `btford.socket-io` module. So what I've did was to have a code like this to mock the dependencies:

```
// Set the app module
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module('btford.socket-io', []);

    module('opensportsAdmin');
});
```

But I'm still getting an error (based on the screenshot).

So my question is, how can you work with third-party libraries for your unit-test? I'm kind of new and didn't find any articles that can help me with my problem.

Here's a reference to my [code](https://gist.github.com/renesansz/6b89469292ae2ce70120).

Comment: you need to inject socketFactory before test case starting.

Comment: But I'm not using a `socketFactory` in my controller. It was being used by the third-party library itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use one internal module for your app and one module for dependencies.
detailed explanation and example here:
[Truly mocking providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047479/truly-mocking-providers/31234448#31234448)